# TypeScript Error TS2345: 'type' is assignable to the constraint of type T, but T could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint Value

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Here is the simple piece of code example. As you see the generic functions gets 1 parameter which is object with 2 properties `v` is based on generic `T` and `cb` is callback functions which takes 1 argument also of type `T` and in each type guard block `cb` called with changed `v`. So why typescript throws this errors? How to solve this?

```
type Value = string | number | string[];

const fn = <T extends Value>(p: {v: T; cb: (v: T) => void}) => {
  const {v, cb} = p;

  if (typeof v === 'number') {
    cb(v + 1); // TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.<br/>'number' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'SelectValue'.
  } else if (typeof v === 'string') {
    cb(`Hi ${v}`); // TS2345: Argument of type '`Hi ${T &amp; string}`' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.<br/>'`Hi ${T &amp; string}`' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'SelectValue'.<br/>Type '`Hi ${string}`' is not assignable to type 'T'.<br/>'`Hi ${string}`' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'SelectValue'.
  } else {
    cb([...v, 1]); // TS2345: Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.<br/>'any[]' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'SelectValue'.
  }
};

// fn call examples
fn({
  v: 1,
  cb: (n: number) => {
    console.log(n);
  },
});

fn({
  v: 'John',
  cb: (n: string) => {
    console.log(n);
  },
});

fn({
  v: [],
  cb: (n: number[]) => {
    console.log(n);
  },
});
```